# Sum of two observables

Tags: rx-java

Suppose two observables:

```
Observable obs1 = Observable.just(1);
Observable obs2 = Observable.just("A");
```

How could I compose from these two another `obs3`, emitting string **1A**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the `zip` operator.  This will take two Observables and combine them with a function, like this:

```
Observable obs1 = Observable.just(1);
Observable obs2 = Observable.just("A");

obs1
   .zipWith(obs2, (a, b) -> String.format("%d%s", a, b))
   .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s));
```